# what is the "Invalid enum. An unacceptable value is specified for an enumerated argument. error?"

Tags: python

I was trying the arcade module but I am having multiples errors and I am confused if anyone can help me solve it I'll be grateful here's the code:

```
import arcade

SCREEN_WIDTH = 640
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 480


def main():
    arcade.open_window(640, 480, "Drawing Example")

    arcade.run()

main()
```

I expected a window to be created but I got this output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\USER\Desktop\Coding\Python\Games\Pixel apocalypse\main.py", line 13, in <module>
    main()
  File "c:\Users\USER\Desktop\Coding\Python\Games\Pixel apocalypse\main.py", line 8, in main
    arcade.open_window(640, 480, "Drawing Example")
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\arcade\application.py", line 763, in open_window        
    _window = Window(width, height, window_title, resizable=resizable, update_rate=None,
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\arcade\application.py", line 130, in __init__
    super().__init__(width=width, height=height, caption=title,
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pyglet\window\win32\__init__.py", line 138, in __init__ 
    super(Win32Window, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pyglet\window\__init__.py", line 603, in __init__       
    self._create()
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\arcade\application.py", line 648, in _create
    super()._create()
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pyglet\window\win32\__init__.py", line 304, in _create
    self.switch_to()
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\arcade\application.py", line 677, in switch_to
    super().switch_to()
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pyglet\window\win32\__init__.py", line 367, in switch_to
    self.context.set_current()
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pyglet\gl\win32.py", line 242, in set_current
    super(Win32Context, self).set_current()
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pyglet\gl\base.py", line 299, in set_current
    gl_info.set_active_context()
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pyglet\gl\gl_info.py", line 97, in set_active_context
    glGetIntegerv(GL_NUM_EXTENSIONS, num_extensions)
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pyglet\gl\lib.py", line 114, in errcheck
    raise GLException('(0x%x): %s' % (error, msg))
pyglet.gl.lib.GLException: (0x500): Invalid enum. An unacceptable value is specified for an enumerated argument.
```

Comment: It looks like a bug in the library, so you'd need to contact the maintainer, but you're not making a window the way they expect in the tutorial. Maybe try that first? https://api.arcade.academy/en/latest/examples/platform_tutorial/step_01.html